# Handling equal nested objects in Realm

Tags: ios, realm

Here is the sample of JSON I'm getting from server:

```
[
    { 
        id = 1, 
        name = "Tagged",
        Tags = [
            {
                id = 1,
                text = "Tag1"
            }
        ]
    },
    { 
        id = 2, 
        name = "Tagged also",
        Tags = [
            {
                id = 1,
                text = "Tag1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

After parsing them to objects I have two root objects with nested equal, but not the same tags, still with equal ids, which I marked as primaryKey(). While saving array of root objects I get pretty expected error:

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to create an object of type 'Tag' with an existing primary key value '1'."

Is there any quick way to replace nested object with link to already saved one on writing base object? Or maybe trigger auto update for nested objects?

---

Edit:
Here are my model and save method:

```
class Title: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var name: String?
    let tags = List<Tag>()
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}

class Tag: Object, BaseObject {
    @objc dynamic var id: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var text: String?

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}

let titles: [Title] = getTitles()
try! Realm().write {
    realm.add(tasks)
}
```

Comment: Could you please add your model/s involved and save method code?

Comment: DanielMartinezCondinanza, added models and saving code.